# PInvokeStackImbalance Not Caused By CallingConvention

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke

I have no idea what the problem is here.

I have a ton of p/invoke calls that are working without incident... except this one.

I've managed to reduce my problem to the following sample code.

If I remove either struct member (either the double or the int) it works fine.

I'm assuming the problem is somehow related to the layout of the struct - but when I do a sizeof() in C and a Marshal.SizeOf() in C#, they both return the same value... so if the struct size is the same in C# and C, what could the problem be?

I'm obviously missing something basic here.

**SampleDLLCode.c**

```
#pragma pack(1)

typedef struct SampleStruct {
    double structValueOne;
    int structValueTwo;
} SampleStruct;

__declspec(dllexport) SampleStruct __cdecl SampleMethod(void);
SampleStruct SampleMethod(void) { 
    return (SampleStruct) { 1, 2 };
}
```

**Build Script**

```
gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -O0 -c -o SampleDLLCode.o SampleDLLCode.c
gcc -shared --out-implib -o SampleDLL.dll SampleDLLCode.o
```

**C# Code**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace SampleApplication
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)]
    public struct SampleStruct {
        public double structValueOne;
        public int structValueTwo;
    } 

    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("SampleDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern SampleStruct SampleMethod();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SampleStruct sample = SampleMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing jumps out...for the heck of it, try swapping the order of the fields in the struct? (both sides, naturally)

Comment: @JerKimball Thanks for looking. Swapping the order of the fields in the struct has no effect. I still get the PInvokeStackImbalance MDA warning.

Comment: Could that be an issue between GCC vs .NET and the double type? Returning a struct with cdecl can lead to compiler dependent issues. Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786192/methods-type-signature-is-not-pinvoke-compatible-while-calling-dll-method

Comment: @SimonMourier In that case, wouldn't the sizeof functions return different values? In C it says my struct is 12 bytes wide. Ditto in .NET. If C is putting 12 bytes on the stack, and .NET is taking 12 off, shouldn't it balance regardless of implementation details - even if the values that came back into .NET were "wrong" (which they aren't)? Also, it works with just the double in the struct.

Comment: I know you said cdecl isn't the issue, but have you tried an alternate calling convention for comparison?

Comment: Good point but if you check the link I sent, it's basically the same size also between C# and c++. What happens if you put 3 ints?

Comment: I have tried your sample and it works just fine for me. I don't get a PInvokeStackImbalance. I have compiled the C code using MinGW and MSYS, with gcc 4.7.2, and I have tested the C# code with VS2010 and VS2012. The only thing I did differently was that I left out `--out-implib` on the second call to gcc. If I use `--out-implib` I get this error: `gcc.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '--out-implib'`.

Comment: @JerKimball - Yes. For the heck of it, I tried StdCall - no dice.

Comment: @Ove - That's interesting. What compiler are you using? I am using MinGW.

Comment: @Steve I am using the MinGW that I have installed using the MinGW installer `mingw-get-inst-20120426.exe`. When installing, I chose `Download latest repository catalogues`, and I have checked `C compiler`, `C++ compiler`, `MSYS basic system` and `MinGW developer toolkit`. The installer created a shortcut to MinGW shell in my start menu, and that's what I used to run the commands in your sample. The gcc version is 4.7.2

Comment: @Ove, and if you goto Debug > Exceptions... > Managed Debugging Assistants > PInvokeStackImbalance is it checked off as "Thrown"? Also, are you using .NET 3.5+? This option was disabled in earlier versions of .NET by default.

Comment: @Steve, the PInvokeStackImbalance is checked as "Thrown" in VS2010 and VS2012. I am using .NET 4 in VS2010 and .NET 4.5 in VS2012. I have tried using the .NET 4 Client Profile as well as .NET 4 full in VS2010, and they both work. No PInvokeStackImbalance is thrown.

Comment: @Ove You are using MS compiler I think

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all let me congratulate you on a very well asked question. It was a delight, for once, to receive all the code that was needed to reproduce the problem.

The problem is due to the slightly different ABIs used by gcc and Microsoft tools for function return values. For return values that can fit into registers, for example `int` return values there are no differences. But since your struct is too large to fit in a single register and there are differences between the APIs in that situation.

For larger return values, the caller passes a hidden pointer to the function. This hidden pointer is pushed onto the stack by the caller. The function writes the return value to the memory address specified by that hidden pointer. The difference in the ABIs is in who pops that hidden pointer off the stack. The Microsoft tools use an ABI that requires the caller to pop the hidden pointer, but the default gcc ABI asks the callee to do that.

Now, gcc being almost infinitely configurable, there is a switch that will allow you to control the ABI. And you can make gcc use the same rules as the Microsoft tools. Doing so requires the [`callee_pop_aggregate_return` function attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html).

Change your C code to be like this:

```
__declspec(dllexport) SampleStruct __cdecl SampleMethod(void) 
    __attribute__((callee_pop_aggregate_return(0)));
    // specifies that caller is responsible for popping the hidden pointer

SampleStruct SampleMethod(void) { 
    return (SampleStruct) { 1, 2 };
}
```

Comment: Bloody well answered - and investigated!

Comment: I love you. Thank you. You're my hero!

Comment: David, quick follow-up question; Is it safe to use that callee_pop_aggregate_return attribute on ALL of my exported functions for my Windows build - or should I ONLY be using it when it's actually applicable? I ask because it'll be easier to just stick with always adding a precompiler macro at the end of my declarations as opposed to determining where specifically I'll need it - so if it's safe, it'll be easier.

Comment: @Steve I'm no gcc expert. I worked this all out from scratch. That said, return types that don't require a hidden pointer come back in a register and so nobody needs to pop anything. So yes, I'm pretty sure that this setting only changes behaviour when return value needs hidden pointer. That's what I take "aggregate return" to mean.

Comment: For anyone who happens across this thread; apparently the "callee_pop_aggregate_return" attribute was added in **GCC v4.6** http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/changes.html I happened to have a version of MinGW which included gcc v4.5.2 (not good enough). Redownloading MinGw didn't help. You must run **mingw-get upgrade** on the command line.

Comment: @Steve The other solution, which I would certainly advocate, is to avoid aggregate return values in the first place. Pass a pointer to the struct as a param, that's an out param in the C#. I'd suggest you go that way if you can modify the DLL. That will allow you to simply avoid issues of differing ABI.

Comment: I had considered that - and I'd even thought about doing that prior to posting the question - but all that code is used on multiple platforms, and by some of our partners, so I wasn't thrilled with that option because it would have meant either breaking API changes or adding additional methods specifically for use on windows (and, ideally, removing those deprecated methods on windows as well). Moving forward, it's definitely something we'll consider - but the ability to retroactively patch the issue by deploying a new version of the DLL for old clients is pretty awesome.

Comment: Remember that changing the ABI is a breaking API change.