# Marshaling structure (that containes arrays) as return value

Tags: c++, arrays, vb.net, pinvoke, marshalling

The C++ code for a structure is the following:

```
typedef struct _a astruct;
struct _a {
    BYTE fi, Sec, *D, *IIV, PV;
    bool Visited;
};
```

and a function which uses it:

`astruct DoPDC(string *InitialData);`

I want to use this function (contained in a DLL) by VB.NET, so I wrote the following code for the structure:

```
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
Public Structure astruct
    Dim fi As Byte
    Dim Sec As Byte
    Dim D As Byte()
    Dim IIV As Byte()
    Dim PV As Byte
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Dim Visited As Boolean
End Structure
```

and the function declaration:

```
    <DllImport("astr.dll", EntryPoint:="DoPDC", BestFitMapping:=False, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl, ThrowOnUnmappableChar:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)> _
    Public Function DoPDC(ByVal InitialData As String()) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)> astruct
    End Function
```

So, I get the miserable error `MarshalDirectiveError` and specifically `Method's type signature is not PInvoke compatible.` I have never seen this error before and there are so many different solutions on the Internet, but no-one has my case, where I pass as parameter an array of strings, returning a structure that contains more arrays!

As a result, I don't know what is wrong: the parameter, the return value, the arrays inside the return value or all together? I am quite confused... Therefore, my question is: how can I modify my VB.NET P/Invoke code, so that it works correctly?

(Note that it is impossible for me to change the C++ DLL, as it is not mine and therefore, I don't have the code...)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your definition of `D` and `IIV`.  You declare them as byte arrays, but the P/Invoke marshaller has no idea how big those arrays are; there is nothing inherent about a pointer-to-byte that conveys length.  If the arrays are variable-length then how is the P/Invoke marshaller to determine this length?  If they always have a known, fixed length then you can use this, where `N` is the fixed length of the array:

```
<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst = N)>
```

If the returned arrays have a dynamic size, and you can determine it somehow after the function has returned, then declare `D` and `IIV` as `IntPtr` and use the methods of [`System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal(v=vs.110).ASPX) to extract the data.

If the pointers point to memory allocated by the function that it expects you to free, you will have to manually free the allocations, which will involve sending those pointers back into an unmanaged function to be freed.

Comment: Tried this, but still get THE SAME error!! I HATE PInvoke... So, it is as I suspected it, I have MULTIPLE errors!! At least I would like to thank you (+1) as I corrected 1 of the infinite errors...

Comment: @Jason This is the only error I see.  Can you paste your code after adding this attribute?

Comment: the structure is the same except that byte() has been replaced by IntPtr and I have learnt elsewhere to use IntPtrs, for example: `Dim out(19) As Byte`
`Marshal.Copy(astruct.D, out, 0, 20)` (it doesn't have length of 20 byte, this is just for demonstration, but anyway I know how to extract the array) If this could help, I have seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786192/methods-type-signature-is-not-pinvoke-compatible-while-calling-dll-method) that GCC does what it says (2nd answer), so maybe the Visual Studio compiler does something similar??

Comment: Hmm, I see.  If you replaced both byte arrays with `IntPtr` then I don't see what could be wrong.  In the C++ code they are void pointers and not arrays, so we don't have to worry about the first answer there.  The second one is interesting.  RVO can be tricky.  You may need to disassemble the DLL in order to figure out if this is what you need to do (it very well could be).

Comment: I don't know assembly, but I can tell you the compiler options used for the DLL.

Comment: @Jason I'm dumb.  See my edit.  The proper unmanaged type is LPArray, not ByValArray.

Comment: Yes, that works too -- just wanted to clarify the alternative.

Comment: @Jason FWIW, the IntPtr approach works fine on Mono.  Not sure why the MS.NET CLR has an issue with it.

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty miserable function to have to pinvoke.  The .NET marshaller has no shot at it, nor do we.  Two basic problems with the arrays in the struct:  there's no way to guess how long they are and there is no reasonable guess at who owns the memory for them and how it should be released.

You'll have to declare them as `IntPtr` in your Structure declaration.  Before you do anything more, write a little test program that makes the call repeatedly.  Observe the returned IntPtr values.  If they are *different* then you need to give up, no way to use pinvoke since you can't release the memory.  A C++/CLI wrapper will be needed.

If they are not different then you have a shot at it.  Use Marshal.Copy() to copy the arrays from the IntPtrs.  You still have to know how many elements to copy however.  Call the C programmer if you don't know.

BTW, the [MarshalAs] for the *bool* is wrong, make it UnmanagedType.U1

Comment: If they are different, that doesn't *necessarily* mean that the old allocations are not being freed.  I have seen functions that will store the allocation somewhere and free it on the next call.  (Of course these are bad, non-thread-safe, non-re-entrant functions.)  Calling it repeatedly for hours and profiling memory usage would probably be a better test.  (Inspecting the disassembly could also work.)

Comment: Hmm, assuming such a bizarre scheme isn't very productive.

Comment: @cdhowie Firstly, I would like to inform you that I have another C function that returns an IntPtr and Marshall.Copy works GREAT on that (have tested it). So, the return array problem is solved (note I don't care about memory leaks, the OS should be able to handle the memory not freed by the process. So, it is a Windows problem, not mine. Also, those arrays don't contain sensitive data, so I don't care much about them). Secondly, I know the number of elements of the arrays. Thirdly, I think this is a returning structure problem, not an array returning one!

Comment: @Jason Yes, the structure does seem to be the primary issue here, though I'm still not 100% sure why.

Comment: @cdhowie If you google my error "Method's type signature is not PInvoke compatible." you will see a hundred of sites ALL concerning some sort of structure returning. So, **I don't think this is a coincidence**, but I cannot understand how to apply their solutions either.

Comment: On second glance I don't think you can even P/Invoke this *at all*, because it is C++.  The argument is `std::string` which is a C++ type, and name mangling is going to make it impossible for the CLR to find the entry point.  You may be stuck writing a C wrapper.